# how to realloc an array of double inside a struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

I would like to dynamically change the size of an array inside a struct.
I got the following structure:

```
struct PolynomStruct {
  double * term;
  unsigned int size;
};

typedef struct PolynomStruct *Polynom;
```

When I try to create a new Polynom I have to reserve memory for the struct to use the variables inside the struct, right?:

```
Polynom res = malloc(sizeof(struct PolynomStruct));
res->size = 10;
```

Afterwards I want to add a double to the term array at index 4.
So it shall look like this [0,0,0,0,2.0000]. 
The first thing I do is to reallocate the memory of the array.

```
  res->term = realloc(5 * sizeof(double));
```

In my opinion the sizeof(res->term) should be 5 * 8 bytes = 40 bytes.
But the following code returns 8.

```
printf("size term: %lu\n",sizeof(res->term));
```

"size term: 8"

Afterwards I tried to do this:

```
res->term[4] = 2;
printf("%f\n",res->term[4] );
```

It prints "2.000000" to stdout. I really dont get how this works.
I would be very happy if someone could give me a hint.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: OT: You should not hide a pointer behind a `typedef`.

Comment: Since `res->term` is of type `double *`, a pointer to double, you get the size of a pointer to double.

Comment: `realloc(5 * sizeof(double))` -- This does not have enough arguments for the call to the `realloc` function.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to add the pointer res->term as first argument. I just tried to write the code which is important for my question, so i rewrited it here and forgot to add the pointer.

Comment: It is incorrect to pass `res->term` as the first argument of `realloc()` until it has been assigned a value.  Your `malloc()` doesn't do that.  If you've been extra good this year, it might happen to give you a block of memory in which the bytes corresponding to `term` happen to represent a null pointer.  In that case, your `realloc()` probably does what you want.  But do yourself a favor and either expicitly set `res->term` to `NULL` or `malloc()` the memory, not `realloc()`, the first time you assign a value to that member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(res->term)` returns size of the pointer, not of the allocated memory.
You need to track manually the allocated amount, i.e. by res->size * sizeof(*term) or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

First you don't want this:

```
Polynom res = malloc(sizeof(struct PolynomStruct));
res->size = 10;
```

You've allocated space for the struct but not initialised the `term` pointer you want:

```
Polynom res = malloc(sizeof(struct PolynomStruct));
if(res==NULL){
  //Handle allocation failure...
}
res_>term=NULL;
res->size = 0;

//Later....
free(res->term);
free(res);
```

That allocates space for the `struct` and initialises the array as empty.
Notice it's fine to pass `NULL` to `free()` it does nothing and returns normally.

Or if you did want to preallocate 10 terms:

```
Polynom res = malloc(sizeof(struct PolynomStruct));
if(res==NULL){
  //Handle allocation failure...
}
res->size = 10;
res_>term=malloc(res->size*sizeof(double));
if(res->term==NULL){
  res->size=0;
  //Handle error...
}

//Later (when finished with res)...
free(res->term);
free(res);
```

That preallocates the array to being 10. If you preallocate you may want to track a `capac` (how much is allocated) and `size` (how much is used). But that's beyond the scope here.

To reallocate write a function ike this:

```
int reallocate(Polynom res,int newsize){
    double *resized=realloc(res->term,newsize*sizeof(double));
    if (resize==NULL){
      //Allocation failed. The array is the same size as before.
      return 1; //Or handle error your own way.
    }
    res->term=resized;
    res->size=newsize;
    //realloc may extend the space allocated in place or realloc space elsewhere.
    //If it does reallocate elsewhere the current contents are just copied over 
    //(byte for byte) and the old space freed. 
    return 0;//Success. No error.
}


//Later (when finished with res)...
free(res->term);
free(res);
```

It's often wise to then `res=NULL;` to avoid confusing mishaps.

Notice if a pointer was returned by `malloc` or `realloc` (and not `NULL`) it must go to `free()` (exactly once).

Also notice `realloc` can reduce the size so `newsize < res->size` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there might be some confusion over pointer vs array. Please read this helpful article: [Are pointers and arrays equivalent in C?](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/10/21/are-pointers-and-arrays-equivalent-in-c)

You don't "change the size of an array inside a struct" because the whole point of having a struct is keeping things stable. Therefore, Polynom res = malloc(sizeof(struct PolynomStruct)) will always allocate the same amount of memo on the heap for res.

If you want to build a heap array of doubles and points term to it, you can do:

```
int member=10; // grow array size by member=member*2 for example
double a[]=malloc(member*sizeof(double));
term=a;
```

This way, you can dynamically grow your array.